# How to unregister JTree from TreeModel while it is not visible?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtree, defaulttreemodel

How can I get a [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) to only listen to its [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) while it is actually visible to the user or at least to have it unregister itself as soon as the corresponding [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) is disposed?

As far as I can see the only case a `JTree` unregisters itself from its model is if you pass it a new model (using `setModel(…)`).

This causes the tree not being garbage collected if the model is referenced from somewhere else. Example: I implemented a `TreeModel` using a [`WatchService`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to have an always up to date model of a file system tree. Even a single listener on the model requires me to keep the `WatchService` informing the model about file system changes, so it cannot be garbage collected. So even if the `JTree` is not visible anymore it is still kept in memory by the model which still needs to get updates from the `WatchService`, although none of this is necessary any longer.

I guess the best way would be to create a new class extending `JTree` that does the registering to and unregistering from the model. If so, which methods are called when the component is shown or disposed? Probably `addNotify()` and `removeNotify()` are good candidates?

Comment: TreeModel? You must have a customized table to begin with... JTables have TableModel.

Comment: Oops, of course I meant `JTree`, not `JTable`, I'll edit my question, thanks! :-P

Answer (score 0):

Using the documentation of JTree: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html.

`JTree` has a protected field called `treeModelListener` which you can remove from the model directly using `JTreeModelListener.removeTreeModelListener()`. If you want to remove your tree model from its own listener at will, extend `JTree` and add the following method:

```
public void unregisterOrWhatever() {
    this.treeModel.removeTreeModelListener(this.treeModelListener);
}
```

If you want to get fancy with listening for window closing events, add a `HierarchyListener` to your `JTree` which listens for `HierarchyEvent.PARENT_CHANGED` events. Whenever the JTree is added to a new window, you can add a `WindowListener` `unregisterOrWhatever` when the window is closed. Don't forget to also remove the `WindowListener` when the `JTree` is removed from a window.